# Position fixed div (or side bar) overlapping with footer

Tags: html, css

Problem: When you make a certain div's position fixed (often used as a side bar, or side menu kind of stuff), and if you continue scrolling down, the div overlaps with the footer.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #07CB6F;
}
#body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3450px;
  background-color: #2FA3F7;
}
#body_inner {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 3450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#side_menu {
  width: 220px;
  height: 270px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FF00AB;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="body">
  <div id="body_inner">
    <div id="side_menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

I did not use any jquery this time. With the codes given above, since the `#side_menu` is set as `height: 270px`, it seems to be okay with the overlapping, however, it still overlaps with the footer if you zoom up the browser (and sometimes depending on the types of browsers and computers).

I would like to know why it happens, and how can it be solved (or prevented).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I used your code to create a snippet, but I think you didn't add all relevant code to it (it looks quite broken). Please edit by adding all relevant code to create a [mcve] of your problem. Press **edit** under the text and than **Edit this snippet**. Add relevant CSS. html and/or JavaScript in each panel. Also, if needed, add any relevant external resources (`.js` or `.css` files) until the problem you are describing can be experienced in snippet. Try to keep code minimal.

Comment: You mean the overlapping? Open the snippet in full page, and scroll until the end and zoom it up like 150%.

Comment: This problem cannot be solved using legacy (box-model) without use of `javascript`. Pick one of the plugins [listed here](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sticky-scroll-plugins/) to achieve this behaviour. My personal favorite is [lockfixed](http://www.directlyrics.com/code/lockfixed/demo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with the solution

https://jsfiddle.net/stc0ogy2/1/

you need to start using the `z-index`, it works like the photoshop layers though the `z-index` will not work without the `position` so you have to add a position like absolute, relative and so on.

**UPDATE**

As @AndreiGheorghiu mentioned you should use some javascript for a better solution, choose one of the libraries from the [list](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sticky-scroll-plugins/) he gave you.

**UPDATE 2**

I found this easy-to-use library that I believe will help you with the fixed side menu, it's called [tether](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether). Hope it helps.

Comment: It no longer overlaps the footer, but it overlaps the header. I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: same solution bro! it's not that hard! I already updated the fiddle @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: How is **covering** the sidebar a solution, Khaled? The idea is not to cover it, but to stop it from overlapping with both header and footer. Fill it up with content and see if it still looks like a professional, or even *good* idea...

Comment: to do it professionally you need some javascript or some library like the **bootstrap affix** other than that this is what the **CSS** is capable of! @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: My point exactly, Khaled. See my comment under the question, maybe? It also happens to be the ***correct*** answer.

Comment: I agree with using some javascript but for our case here all what we have is the **CSS** maybe our friend who asked will use some javascript in the future @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to solve this without javascript right? Using javascript is the simplest way to solve for the moment...

Comment: yes @jeannedareca , **Javascript** will do exactly what you want, my solution is the far what **CSS** can do

Comment: @jeannedareca check the update I added, hope the library helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is looking to take up 100% of the width space at the bottom and a side bar that wants to take up 220px of the width. On a small screen your menu and footer are fighting for space because its not mathematically possible for one item to take up 100% of space and another item to sit next to it.

You won't notice a problem full screen on most desktops because your menu is too heightwise to be noticeable.

Ideally when declaring your width for the menu and footer you want to use

```
calc()
```

to enable resizing without causing overlap.

https://jsfiddle.net/nu8av25m/ a quick example I put together to demonstrate how it works.

```
<body>
    <div class="navigation">menu</div>
    <div class="main">main body</div>
    <footer>footer</div>
</body>

.navigation {
    Width:50px;
    Height:100%;
    Background-color: red;
    Float:left
}

.main{
    Width: calc(100% - 200px);
    Height: calc(100% - 100px);
    Background-color: blue;
    Right:0;
}

Footer{
    Width: calc(100% - 100px);
    Height: 50px;
    Background-color:green;
    Bottom: 0
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your advice but you are not answering my question!